# How to write a DataFormatString for an int with a leading pound sign?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `int` property that I want to display on an MVC form with padded leading zeroes and a pound sign in front.  How do I accomplish that?  Here's what I have so far:

```
    [DisplayName("Compat Rule Number")]
    [Range(1, 999)]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "None", DataFormatString = "{0:000}")]
    public int CompatRuleNumber { get; set; }
```

So, for a value `12`, I want the display to be **#012**.  As I write this, I'm thinking that `"#{0:000}"` might do the trick.  Will that work?

Comment: Well, a pound sign doesn't quantify as an integer.  So what you would need to do, would be to use Razor on the front-end to parse the integer field as a string with your formatting.

Comment: I was hoping to get something that the scaffolding engine could figure out rather than customize CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your over thinking, we already know that a pound isn't a valid integer.  An integer doesn't contain any specific formatting that would append a pound.  You would have to convert the integer into a String.

The String will allow such formatting.  As you iterate through your model, you could simply do the following:

```
@{ String.Format("#{0}", CompatRuleNumber); }
```

That would format in said manner, I'm not sure if you could apply it to *Data Scaffolding* while it is of an integer type.